Delete an object in OpenStack Swift
Swift official document says:

To replicate deletions in addition to creations, every deleted record or file in the system is marked by a tombstone. The replication process cleans up tombstones after a time period known as the consistency window. This window defines the duration of the replication and how long transient failure can remove a node from the cluster. Tombstone cleanup must be tied to replication to reach replica convergence.

https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/admin/objectstorage-replication.html
I wonder:

What will happen if a storage node still doesn't know about the deletion (in other words, the object on the node is not marked by a tombstone) after the consistency window time is up. Let say this node cannot communicate temporarily with the others due to a network problem.
When it is available again, the object will be replicated to the other nodes, won't it?
What is the solution?

